# Sublime Text 3 - lose indent

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to resolve something that's causes me some unwanted keystrokes.  Whenever I've create a new line of code thats indented (i.e. new CSS selector, with no actual CSS yet) and use the Application Switcher to move to my browser, I come back to ST and the indent is gone.  I found a thread on here that points to overriding the default setting for "trim_automatic_white_space"..

`"trim_automatic_white_space": false,`

But that didn't resolve it.  Doesn't matter if I'm writing PHP, JavaScript, or CSS.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: do you perhaps have `"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,` and `"save_on_focus_lost": true,` in your preferences?

Comment: Actually yes, in my user preferences I have them set to yes.  I changed `"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,` to false and that did it.  Thank you!